# How to use Flex Layout inside Listview Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to create a Flex Layout Inside Listview Item Template?
Cant find any solution to create a dynamically data binding like listview

I want to create this layout using flex layout,How to create this?

[image]

Comment: This screen can't be created with Single layout. It will require multiple nested Layouts. But yes you can use FlexLayout as the top level Layout.

Comment: You can ask for help about specific problems you are facing. But don't expect others to develop the full screen for you.